# APP nodejs: impedir logs na janela do terminal

Tags: node.js, express.js

Criei um aplicação em Nodejs com Express e quando coloco essa aplicação para rodar (com `npm start`), ficam aparecendo uns logs na janela do terminal em que estou conectado a cada página que eu acesso das minhas rotas.
É para ser assim mesmo? Tem como desabilitar e é bom que seja desabilitado?

logs na janela do terminal:

```
GET /javascripts/jquery/jquery-ui.js 304 32.627 ms - -
GET /javascripts/jquery/datepicker-pt-BR.js 304 32.307 ms - -
GET /javascripts/chartjs/Chart.js 304 32.109 ms - -
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte linha de código:

```
console.log = function(){}
```

Qualquer chamada a `console.log` será "ignorada" a partir desse ponto

Se quiser ativar/desativar, pode atribuir `console.log` a uma variável para depois recuperar

Ex.:

```
var log = console.log;
console.log = function(){};//Desativa
console.log = log;//Ativa novamente
```

Comment: grato pelo retorno. Mas eu gostaria de saber se o que causam esses logs na tela é para continuar assim. Se não for para continuar assim, essa maneira que você indicou é única maneira? ou existe algum recurso habilitado por padrão na estrutura básica de projeto que o Express cria, que fica gerando esses logs, e que pode ser desabilitado?

Comment: Não entendo muito de nodejs, mas acho que não há problemas com o log, essa opção que eu passei é genérica em javascript

Comment: ok, obrigado pelo retorno